# PHP: is it possible to use php to get the MAC address?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how can i get the MAC Address using PHP. I look over the manual and i don't see any function to work on this as of now.

Comment: It is not the layer for which PHP was made for. PHP works on application level, or TCP when you open a descriptor to a port. I don't think there are binding to reach into lower levels.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run `ifconfig` (or `ipconfig /all` on windows) and parse the result.

Comment: I do hope he's running Linux though.

Comment: This will only work for the server's MAC address. There is no way to get the client's MAC in PHP. The MAC address is not passed along from hop to hop.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output of "ifconfig" command or you can parse file "/proc/net/arp". They both contain MAC addr.